# Cannot connect Nano RP2040 Connect running on Micropython to WiFi

Tags: wifi, microcontroller, micropython, rp2040

I have a Nano RP2040 Connect with Micropython on it. I need to connect it to WiFi. Micropython documentation says I need to import the "network" module, but when I try importing it, I get the `no module named 'network'` error. I assume the module is only for ESP32 & ESP8266 boards. If anyone has connected to WiFi with a Nano RP2040 Connect on Micropython, please help me out.

P.S.: I have tried CircuitPython, and it worked great, but I need to run a Tensorflow Lite model on my RP2040, and CircuitPython does not have a library for running TFLite, unlike Micropython.

Comment: if you follow this guide, the version of MicroPython that gets installed will come with the Network library https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/nano-rp2040-connect/rp2040-openmv-setup I just wish the normal guide worked https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/microcontrollers/micropython.html#what-is-micropython

Comment: Im stuck on this as well. Cant find any good tutorials to make a "simple" http request.

Comment: The above comment recomends OpenMV, I tried it but that did not work well at all with the Nano Connect. Thonny and MicroPython worked way more reliably. I ended up installing CircuitPython and using MU editor to connect to Wifi. Never could figure out how to connect to WiFi with Micropython.

Answer (score 0):

you can get all available modules with (untested yet from me, but can help maybe)

> help(modules)

also this for Wifi could help you: [Raspberry Pi Pico W: Sensor-Daten-Logging übers Netzwerk](https://www.elektronik-kompendium.de/sites/raspberry-pi/2708141.htm)